# Python replace - is there a trick to it? replacing '[%2C}'

Tags: python, csv, replace

I have a series of text in a csv file:

```
7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298}
```

Is there a trick to getting replace to replace the [%2C] ?

```
with open('C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\unewuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit', "rb") as fin, open('C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\unewuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit', "wb") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
    new_row = []
    for item in row:
        new_row.append(item.replace('[%2C]', ','))
    print row, "->", new_row
    writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Now I get a file, but it is empty, and I get this errorr message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 6, in <module>
    for item in row:
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Comment: the second for loop `for item in row:` should be inside `for row in reader:` see the the code i have updated

Comment: _" First off, you want to convert [%2C] to a comma, so that the csv module will parse it correctly."_ If Josh Smeaton is right, then it means that your file isn't a CSV file at start. - _" I am sure it is annoying to have a newbie like me provide only half of the information."_ Oh , yes. But you are not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
In [47]: s.replace('[%2C]', ',')
Out[47]: '7858.35924983374,1703.69341358077,-3.075},7822.85045874375,1730.80294308742,-3.53962362760298}'
```

try this...

```
for row in row_reader:
    new_row = []
    for item in row:
        new_row.append(item.replace('[%2C]', ','))
    print row, "->", new_row
    row_writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Ok, so sadly I can not seem to make this work:                              in_file = 'C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\unewuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit'
    out_file = 'C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\u2newuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit'
    
    row_reader = csv.reader(open(in_file, "rb"))
    row_writer = csv.writer(open(out_file, "wb"))
    s = s.replace('[%2C]', ',')
    writer.writerow(s)

Comment: it should be `row_writer.writerow(s)` not `writer.writerow(s)`

Comment: avasal, thank you for noticing the typo (it is late for me). sadly, it still does not work.  I cant seem to get a file out.

Comment: Nothing.  Strange.  I just ran another script on the same series of files, same folder, got results.  But for some reason this one doesnt. Is it because the text has {    and     } in it?

Comment: no, those are only characters, they would not create any problem

Comment: avasal, I updated the code above to reflect your suggestion.  I am a step closer, now I get an empty file and an error message.

Comment: updated above code to reflect changes - now is a different error message.  avasal, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You want [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

```
val.replace('[%2C]', ',')
```

Edit:

Now that I understand your problem, I will be a little more descriptive. First off, you want to convert `[%2C]` to a comma, so that the csv module will parse it correctly.

So like I said, you need to clean your data.

```
in_file = 'C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\unewuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit'
out_file = 'C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\u2newuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit.csv'
csv_outfile = 'C:\IM\C3D\CommonLibraries\u2newuoxhwt5k.wi2.conduit.csv.out'

with open(out_file, w) as outfile:
    with open(in_file) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.replace('[%2C]', ','))
```

Now you can do your CSV parsing:

```
reader = csv.reader(out_file)
writer = csv.writer(csv_outfile)
for row in reader:
    # do some processing on the row, which is a list of separated items
    new_row = row + ["another item"]
    writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, so it should read: val = val.replace('[%2C',',') - where i currently have new_row..... ?

Comment: Thanks Josh.  My apologies, I am sure it is annoying to have a newbie like me provide only half of the information.  Sorry about that.  THanks for the update.  Let me try it out.

Comment: Yeah, see something wierd is going on.  It will not give me a file out.

Comment: It must be something in the file itself, or the way it is formatted.

Comment: ftp://ftp.whoi.edu/pub/usgs/txt.zip if you are curious

Comment: @MattfromMaine don't write to the file being read. Use a different filename for the outfile, and you'll be fine I think.